# Specific configurations for different items using same table

Tags: java, json

So we have an `ITEM`, `TV`, `LCD` and `PROJECTOR`.

We have `DAO` and `Service object` for `TV`, `LCD` and `PROJECTOR` that also are `ITEM` objects. Meaning that those tables all `extends` the `ITEM` table.

You can access these items through an UI and an API service.

Right now, I am in the need to put specific UI configurations that are not related at all with the `API`. Lets say that I need in the UI a configuration for each item to display or not display an image of the item on it, lets call it `showImageFlag`. This value can be modified from the Item's UI, this is a checkbox.

I've been thinking about a few options here:

1. Add a column `SHOW_IMAGE_FLAG` to the `ITEM` table and it's `DAO` and service object. On the service object put a `@JSonIgnore` flag so it is ignored on the API side, but we can use it normally in the UI. ------- My concern with this approach is that in the future we might need more configuration for these items or maybe others than `tv`, `lcd` and `projector`. So this will always will push us to add a new column to the table. Another concern is that we might be migrating all form post ui to use the REST API, so we are going to have to do something about that JsonIgnored property.
2. A `ITEM_CONFIG (id, item_id, configuration, value)` table `FK`ed to the `ITEM`.`id` with a key/value approach to save N configuration related to specific items. So on every web controller I will be passing a `ItemConfig` object with all configurations related to the requested `ITEM`. -------- My concern with this one, is how should I map this to the form (using `spring mvc`) and how should I persist when the configuration changes on the UI.

Please free to comment and suggest any new option for this.

Comment: From OO perspective I would *not* use the first approach.

Comment: The question is about programming patterns, which is definitely not an "opinion based" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a config table for items called `ITEM_CONFIG` (`ITEM_ID`, `UI_PROPERTIES`)

On the `UI_Properties` I save a `JSON` string, which is mapped to a String propertie on the `DAO` model, but as a `HashMap<String, Object>` on the service model.

I have a converter that maps the value from the dao model to the `hasmap` on the service object, "automatically".

On the controller (in the BaseController, parent of every WebController [not rest]), I added a method to get the config from the ItemConfigService and then set the value on the response (Model in SpringMVC) using the `hasmap key` as the `parameter` and the value as the `parameter` value.

This is working very clean and we haven't had any issues since last week.

Answer (score 2):

Second point is more feasible.
Also,you can have another service layer which will be responsible for saving mapping part and below service layer there will be UI controller layer which will actually map the changes to its undergoing presentation i.e. UI layer.

Answer (score 1):

I would think about adding `Item(id)--ItemUI(item_id)` as 1:1.

Then you can add all your UI specific about an item to the ItemUI attributes.

Also you could request UI configuration with a second call to another service.

Answer (score 1):

From the two options I'll go for number one. The only problem that comes up is when the UI is migrated to use the API. In that case you won't be using `@JsonIgnore`, instead you will be using Json Views.

You can create classes representing specific views on your data and use them to tag your attributes with `@JsonView(MyView.class)`. Finally, you can serialize your beans using `objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, beanInstance, MyView.class);`

In your case you could create an view class `MyAPIView` and annotate all fields but `SHOW_IMAGE_FLAG` with `@JsonView(MyAPIView.class)` (Note `MyAPIView` is an empty class used for tagging purposes, with no logic nor attributes).

If you call `objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, beanInstance, MyAPIView.class);` you wont serialize the `SHOW_IMAGE_FLAG` attribute. If you call `objectMapper.writeValue(out, beanInstance)` you will serialize the attribute.

You must determine at runtime the view to be used. If you are using OAuth you could select view depending on the connected client.

Eventually, you can create several views and apply inheritance. Take a look at [jacksons doc](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews).